# CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

Tags: rest-api

I am connecting to external system when i update the existing records in sfdc,automatically 
trigger call the webservice and get data from external system and pplaced in salesforce field
but it showing an error

Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a1Uf0032323234; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, qlineUpdater: execution of AfterUpdate

caused by: System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method:

```
trigger qlineUpdater on Quote_Item__c (after update) {
for (Quote_Item__c ql : Trigger.old) {
  QuolineUpdater.updateQline(ql.Id, ql.Name);
}

}
```

Apex Class

```
   public class QuolineUpdater {
//Future annotation to mark the method as async.
 @Future(callout=true)
 public static void updateQline(String id, String name) {

//construct an HTTP request
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/salesforceApi/salesforce.txt');
req.setMethod('GET');

//send the request
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

//check the response
if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {


  Quote_Item__c  ql = new Quote_Item__c (Id=id);
  ql.Comment_On_Product__c = res.getBody();
  update ql;
} else {
  System.debug('Callout failed: ' + res);
 } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you make an attempt to understand the error message ? It is self-explanitory.

> caused by: System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called
>   from a future or batch method:

Your design does this:

```
Trigger -> Do async call out
async call out-> call trigger
```

This would result in a recursive, never ending operation if you do not build-in conditions to regulate when what needs to be done.

**update:**
You need to consider the following: Under what conditions do you want that trigger to call the external system ? Always ? Only if specific fields are updated ? I expect it should only call the external system has **not** been done before, so that is what you need to check first in your code.

Additionally, your current implementation will make a call out per every record updated, I would advise you, if possible to attempt to do the call out once for all records in your current trigger scope.

Comment: How to change my trigger..?? any suggestions.

Comment: Sathy, put some thought into this yourself. I'll update my answer with a starting point.

Comment: i want to call external system when ever name field update.i want to call external system only name field update case only.

Comment: Then that is what you must include in your code. So that it ONLY does that when the old name is not the same as the new name.

Comment: can you plz give me some update code where i want to change.

Comment: Try to translate what i said above into apex code. Consider that you need to compare the old and the new value, the trigger.newMap is a usefull thing in doing so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14400/discussion-between-sathya-and-samuel-de-rycke)